# i have a questions when i use iOS-Universal-Framework

Tags: ios, frameworks

The `iOS-Universal-Framework's` page : https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework
It is an XCode project template to build universal (arm6, arm7, and simulator) frameworks for iOS.

I have build my framework by use this template,but i got a problem,i have pack all my class in the template,including a macro definition `#define kCOMPANYID 2` in a .h file `Macro.h`,but the problem is ... the kCOMPANYID must can be modified by the one who use my framework,so the `kCOMPANYID` must define out of the framework,but the problem is , some classes in my framework must use the `kCOMPANYID`，so it is a conflict,i don't know how to do,please help me,thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should avoid `#define` as much as possible

one way is to make a setter/getter function to for it

e.g.

```
// public header file

void SetCompanyId(int value);
// int GetCompanyId();  // it can be in public header or private header

// some .m or .c or .cpp file

static int companyId;

int GetCompanyId() { return copanyId; }
void SetCompanyId(int value) { companyId = value; }
```

or if the user mush provide a id, just make it a global variable. you can add `const` to it so the value can't change

```
// header file in your framework
extern const int kCompanyId;

// some implementation file in user code
const int kCompanyId = 2;
```

then user must provided a company id otherwise it will have linker error